# Programmatically append existing component to existing v-model in VueJS

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

Like the title says, Im trying to append a `vue-component` to an existing `v-model`

The only thing i found on the internet was the `v-for` solution to add more elements, but that is not what I want to do since this v-model could have multiple components

**chat.vue**

The V-model im trying to append to

```
<template>
   <ul class="chat-ul" v-model="messages">
       <chat-entry :name="name" :message="text" direction="left"></chat-entry>
   </ul>
</template>
```

Here is where im stuck, how i can add the components

```
<script>
Vue.component('chat-entry', require('./entry.vue'));

module.exports = {
    data: function () {
        return {
            name: 'Default name',
            message: 'Default message',
            messages: null,
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        // This is the what i want to achive
        this.messages.append('chat-entry', {direction: 'left', message: 'hello', name: 'HeatON'});


        this.$http.get('/etc/yelp.xi').then(response => {
            for (let q in response.body.arr) {
                this.messages.append('chat-entry', {direction: 'left', message: q.message, name: q.name});
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**entry.vue**

```
<template>
    <div v-if="direction == 'left'">
        <li>
            <div class="message-data">
                <span class="message-data-name"><i class="fa fa-circle you"></i> {{ name }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="message you-message">  {{ message }} </div>
        </li>
    </div>

    <div v-else>
        <li class="clearfix">
            <div class="message-data align-right">
                <span class="message-data-name">{{ name }}</span> <i class="fa fa-circle me"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="message me-message float-right"> {{ message }}  </div>
        </li>
    </div>

</li>
```

Is something like this even possible? if not, what is the proper approach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Basically, you want to show a `chat-entry` component for each message?

Comment: No, then i could just use the v-for method, what i want to do is mixin any component in my loop